# Cancel Bangaldeshi passport and obtain Sri Lanka passport

Tags: passports, bangladeshi-citizens

My Wife was born in Kuwait and has a Bagaldeshi passport.
Her father is a Bangaldeshi and mother is a Sri Lankan.

Her mother made her Sri Lankan birth certificate specifying she was born in Kuwait and made her Sri Lankan national ID card when she was teenager. She had the Sri Lankan citizenship until 21 and she has documents for that also but since she was away. She couldn't apply for the Sri Lankan citizenship when she reached 21.

Now she came to Sri Lanka and got married to me who is a Sri Lankan. She wants to retain the Sri Lankan citizenship and apply for the Sri Lankan passport. We went to the passport office in Sri Lanka and they asked us to cancel the Bangladeshi passport.
We went to Bangladeshi embassy in Sri Lanka. However, they want documents from the passport office in Sri Lanka asking to cancel the passport but passport office says that no letter will be provided since my wife had the citizenship until 21 and we are now stuck?
What should be the process here?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this or how the system works in Sri Lanka, however to me it seems a little odd that your wufe would be required to cancel her Bangladesh passport in order to get a Sri Lanka passport.  Both countries allow dual citizenship, and being a citizen of both countries she should be able to have a passport for each.  To me it seems she needs to renew (?) her Sri Lankan citizenship before there is any discussion on passports.

Comment: None of us (so far) appear familiar with the laws of Sri Lanka and Bangladesh regarding multiple passports and citizenships. While the advice reported by the OP from the passport office is Sri Lanka seems odd, I think here we're all just extrapolating from other countries' behaviors...i.e., guessing.